# How to refresh data during a long request in Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The scenario is user can click a button and call a method, the method will run a python script, and the script will execute about 1~2 minute and during the execution time, I want to update the results on the webpage.

How could I achieve this?

How should I store the python script's output and sned it to the webview in real time?
and when the task finished , the webview will show finished.

Answer (score 1):

The way I accomplished this in the past was when you send your long async request (the python script) you return a job_id to the view.  The back end job continually updates it's progress to the db keyed on the job_id.

The view in the meanwhile uses a polling script (setTimeout) or JQuery.delay() that async polls the server on a suitable refresh interval.

I prefer this polling technique over the alternative push for most cases (but not all)